# Start WildFly with nohup standalone full

Tags: java, linux, shell, nohup, wildfly-11

I want to start the WildFly 11 using the standalone-full.xml instead standalone.xml.

So I have to execute the command:

```
sh standalone.sh -c standalone-full.xml
```

inside folder wildfly-11.0.0.Final/bin/.

But if I want to start the WildFly in silence mode with **nohup**, it doesn't start with parameter `-c standalone-full.xml`.

I tried with:

```
nohup ./standalone.sh  -b 0.0.0.0 -c standalone-full.xml >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

But it does not work.

What is the correct command to start WildFly with standalone-full.xml in silence mode in Linux?

**Server information**: `cat /etc/*-release`

```
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
VERSION="7.4 (Maipo)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VARIANT="Server"
VARIANT_ID="server"
VERSION_ID="7.4"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.4 (Maipo)"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.4:GA:server"
```

Thanks.

Comment: What didn't work about the `nohup` command?

Answer (score 2):

**Use the below cammand.**

```
nohup sh standalone.sh -c standalone-full.xml > /dev/null &
```